# How can i match this directory path and its next following line

Tags: regex

I used this regex `if($tmp =~ /(wot.*)\b/)`    (`$tmp` refers to the data mentioned below) to match just the path `\wot\maks\xxx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx .06.55Z` but i don't get the next line using the regex i mentioned above, i am able to get just `\wot\maks\xxx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx` how can i get the whole path

```
\wot\maks\xxx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx
 .06.55Z

    06/15/2017  09:06 PM               111 ja.xml
                   1 File(s)            211 bytes
```

Comment: note that with `wot.*\b` the word boundary always matches, whatever the string after `wot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the regex to `if($tmp =~ /(wot.*\n.*)\b/)`

Comment: how can i make the new line parameter optional ,because this regex is not reading paths which are small and the path is just a single line  ,for example the path is just   `\wot\maks\xxx\xxxx\xxx\xxxxxxxxx\xxxxxxxxx` and there is no continuation of the path

Comment: i found it ,had to remove `\b` argument

Answer (score 0):

/(wot.*)\s\S+\b/ worked for me.

Have you tried testing solutions on a regex testing site? I find it handy when trying to tune regex.

I like http://regexr.com/ for testing.